# Resending phone_number attribute verification code in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way in **AWS SDK CognitoIdentityServiceProvider** to resend a phone_number attribute change verification code for a **CONFIRMED** user?

I have set phone_number attribute to be verified in **Cognito**. `adminUpdateUserAttributes()` sends the verification code. But I have failed to find a way of resending the verification code. This is a necessity in the use case i am working on.

So far I have tried doing a `adminUpdateUserAttributes()` with the same phone number. It doesn't seem like it resend the verification code. With a new number, it does.

I cant do a `deleteUserAttributes()` and an update again, as the pool configuration sets the phone number as required.

Not sure if its relevant; but note that I have to pretty much use the **CognitoIdentityServiceProvider** admin APIs as Sign UP is also disabled in the User pool.

To sum it up, I am looking for a solution where I can resend the verification code for phone_number attribute in a confirmed user in Cognito User Pool.

Comment: Hi! Did you come up with a solution? I have the same situation :(

Answer (score 1):

This is the method in AWS Api reference that resends OTP code for this flow:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUserAttributeVerificationCode.html

Then in my service, using AWS Java SDK, I call it:

```
    public void resendCodeAttributeVerification(String accessToken) {
    cognitoClient.getUserAttributeVerificationCode(new GetUserAttributeVerificationCodeRequest()
            .withAttributeName(PHONE_NUMBER)
            .withAccessToken(accessToken));
     }
```